# How to search a MySQL database using data from a form using Multiple fields

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have this form here:
[image: My Form]

I'm writing a PHP Script to be able to search my table using the data obtained from the form above. As you can see, it consists of select boxes, date ranges and input boxes.

I have already wrote this script here and it is working for plain text boxes only. I don't know how incoporate select boxes with multiple options.

Also, I'm not sure whether am doing the correct thing. Because it seems am forced to rename my name attributes to match the table columns. It is tedius because my table has over 150 columns.

Here is my code:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
foreach($this->fields as $field){

        if(isset($_POST[$field]) && $request->get($field) != '') {

            $data = $request->get($field);

            $this->conditions[] = "`$field` = '" . $data . "'";
        }

    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM csv_data_final ";

    if(count($this->conditions) > 0) {
        $query .= "WHERE " . implode (' AND ', $this->conditions); 
    }

return $results = DB::select( $query ); // I'm using Laravel's Query Builder
}
```

Comment: if you want to do it your way, check if `$_POST is an array. If it is, modify your function.

Comment: Just going to go out and say that your code is susceptible to SQL injections since you just shove the data into the query string. If this doesn't have an answer in a few hours I'll provide one (it's late and I can't coherently write a full one at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

> Multiple select boxes, Multiple checkboxes always gets posted as
>   arrays.
>   Other fields like Single Select, texbox, textarea or radio get posted as string.

Check if your posted field is an array.

```
if (isset($_POST[$field]) && $request->get($field) != '') {
  $data = $request->get($field);
  if (is_array($data) {
    foreach ($data as $curr) {
      $this->conditions[] = "`$field` = '" . $curr . "'";
    }
  }
  else {
    $this->conditions[] = "`$field` = '" . $data . "'";
  }
}
```